# Can i hide a div without a class or id? (Freshdesk)

Tags: html, css, freshdesk

I'm creating a support site with Freshdesk. Now i have a problem that there is an empty bar under my footer. I find out that this is because of a div that is nowhere to be found in my own code. this div has no class and no id and is not in another div or section. So I can't call it in my css to delete it and I can't give it a class or id. I also cannot find this div if I do "display frame source" but I do see it when I do "inspect element". Someone know a way how i can solve this?

[This is wat i see when i do element inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hisq.png)

[This is what i see when i do display fram spource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvmdN.png)

[This is the empty bar under my footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNDCx.png)

If you need more information please tell me.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for the tip, I already have an answer I will pay attention next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select a HTML element by an attribute. In your case, [rel] would probably be best.

```
div[rel=tmpClipBoard] {
   display:none;
}
```